# How to combine two classes in java

Tags: java, class

Right now I have both of these in separate java files, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine them both together. When I combine them and run it usually only one class will actually work and the other doesn't do anything. I've tried getting rid of one class and combining them into one large class but then I get the error error: method main(String[]) is already defined in class lapTimes public static void main (String[] args)

```
class GFG
{

    static void ConvertSectoDay(int n)
    {

        n %= 3600;
        int minutes = n / 60 ;

        n %= 60;
        int seconds = n;

        System.out.println( minutes + " "
                           + "minutes " + seconds + " "
                           + "seconds ");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        
        int n = 200;
        ConvertSectoDay(n);

    }
}

public class lapTimes {
    
  public void lap1(int lap) {
    System.out.println("How many seconds for lap one: " + lap);
  }
  public void lap2(int lap) {
    System.out.println("How many seconds for lap two: " + lap);
  }
  public void lap3(int lap) {
    System.out.println("How many seconds for lap three: " + lap);
  }
  public void lap4(int lap) {
    System.out.println("How many seconds for lap four: " + lap);
  }
   
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    lapTimes run = new lapTimes();   
    run.lap1(34);
    run.lap2(54);
    run.lap3(43);
    run.lap4(61);              
  }
}
```

Comment: A Java program has a single `main` entrypoint. That's the way... well, most programming languages ever written work. If you want something to happen, it needs to be called from `main`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: The problem is more fundamental than this.  A Java class cannot have two or more methods with the same name and argument types.  Not `main`.  Not any other name.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all of the methods in your `GFG` and `lapTimes` classes into a single class, you obviously have two methods called `main` with arguments `String[] args`.  That is not valid Java.

You cannot have two `static` methods (or two instance methods) with the same and the same argument types ... in the same class.

Why?  Because if you did, then Java would not know *which method* to use when something calls `main` ...

So, if you want your *combined* class to do the *stuff* done by both existing `main` methods, then the obvious solution is to *combine the `main` methods into one*; e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 200;
    ConvertSectoDay(n);

    NewClass run = new NewClass();   
    run.lap1(34);
    run.lap2(54);
    run.lap3(43);
    run.lap4(61);              
}
```

---

But this looks conceptually wrong.  You now have a class that represents *both* a 4 lap race ... and ... whatever a `GFG` is supposed to represent.

1. You should use class names that *indicate* the purpose of the class.  (I have know idea what `GFG` means!)

   It only takes a few seconds to *type* a descriptive name.  Choosing an appropriate name may take a bit longer ... but it will take far more time for *someone else* to understand your code if you use opaque names.  You should be writing your code for other people to read.  (The other people includes yourself, in 5 years time, when you have totally forgotten what the `GFG` class is supposed to do.)
2. You should not combine unrelated abstractions and functions into a single class.  It makes your code confusing.
3. You should follow Java style rules for identifiers:

   - A class name **should not** start with a lowercase letter.
   - A method name **should not** start with a uppercase letter.